# Is there something similar to Twig filters that I can use in Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Twig has this awesome feature called [Twig Filters](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#filters) which allow you to change the variables that you send to your view, from within the view without messing with the data model.

```
{ variable_name | filter_name }
```

This makes it super-duper readable and clean. Filters can be lowercase, encoding, raw text or you can build your own.

Question is simple: I really miss this kind of functionality, what's the best way to implement something like this in Laravel using Blade?

Comment: See this topic on github: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10876

Comment: A [custom directive](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#extending-blade) would probably be the closest bet.

Answer (score 2):

as i know Blade don't offer this functionality of filters, but u can create a helper file that can has many functions helper and every function has her logic.

in this link u can find how to create a helper file with functions and call them inside ur blade file [tutorial how to create helper function](https://medium.com/teknomuslim/how-to-create-helper-functions-in-laravel-d769d12218d4)